# Command 'describe table' not authorized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to run the statement `DESCRIBE TABLE dwh.ods.users` with the role PUBLIC.
I have already grant privileges to role public with:

```
grant all privileges on schema ods to public;
```

However, when I try to run the query, I get the following error:
SQL compilation error:

```
Table 'DWH.ODS.USERS' does not exist or not authorized.
```

With the role USERADMIN it works. How could I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to grant SELECT on table, USAGE on schema and database:

```
grant usage on database DWH to public;
grant usage on schema DWH.ODS to public;
grant select on table DWH.ODS.USERS to public;
```

Answer (score 2):

You also have to grant USAGE on the database. Granting all privileges on the schema doesn't mean granting privileges for the database.

```
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE <database> TO ROLE <role>;
```

In your case:

```
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE dwh TO ROLE public;
```

You can find more info about the USAGE-right here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html

Comment: Same error?
Also try to grant usage on the schema. Not sure whether its included in all privileges or not.

Comment: Addition: Please also grant SELECT on the table to public.